# GDB - step in to statically linked libstdc++

Tags: c++, gdb, libstdc++

For reasons beyond the scope of this question I have to statically link the libstdc++ to my executables. The practical downside is that now GDB can't step in to the stdlib symbols. When I was using the shared linked variants of my executable GDB had no issues to show me the accompanying source files (after I had installed the source package through apt-get under ubuntu which installed it under /build)

How can I step into libstdc++ functions when it is statically linked to an executable in GDB, under Ubuntu (14.04)?

Comment: I'm afraid you'd need the static stdc++ lib with debug symbols. I don't know if for ubuntu there are such thinks as seperated debug symbol packages for static libs.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu package `libstdc++6-4.8-dbg` provides the static library with debug symbols at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/libstdc++.a`; try building your executable against it and then run `gdb`.

Comment: That still does not improve the situation. I've temporarily moved the non-debug static library to be sure I got an expected error, then added a linker path with '-L' to the debug directory: `usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/` then linking succeeded, but still no stepping into functions

Comment: Try the build with `g++ -static-libgcc` as described by [Johan Petersson](http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/06/static-libstdc/).

Comment: Not working either, I confirmed with 'ldd' that I indeed no longer have dependencies on libgcc as well as libstdc++